# Getting exact path for specific file in Finder

Tags: python, macos, finder

I want to find the exact path for an image in my Downloads folder on my Mac. I know it's in the Downloads folder so in my Python project I listed the path as

```
~/Untitled/Users/ivymatch/Downloads/test2.pdf
```

However I am getting a file not found error, even though I know there is a test2.pdf in my Downloads folder. So I am guessing there is an error in my path. How do I get an exact file path that I can then copy and paste into my code. Right clicking the image and clicking 'Get Info' is not getting the job done (see below).

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsH3Y.png)

Comment: Odd. I wonder where does that `~/Untitled` prepended part come from.

Comment: My disk is called Untitled.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. That path makes no sense, no matter if your disk is called Untitled or Titled.

Comment: OK. So what should I do instead?

Comment: "[...] what should I do instead?" to change that path. `~` is supposed to be `/Users/USER_NAME/` - don't put the disk name right after the `~`.

Answer (score 1):

Your path needs to be corrected to :

```
~/Downloads/test2.pdf
```

where `~/` means path to user

Comment: @ivymatch Can you do ``ls ~/Untitled/Users/ivymatch/Downloads`` ?

Comment: I get no such file on directory, but I can do the ~/Downloads/test2.pdf

Comment: If you can do can do the ~/Downloads/test2.pdf then why you are getting error?

Comment: I'm not sure. Which is why I asked this question.

Comment: Can you check file existence by python code. os.path.exists(r"~/Downloads/test2.pdf"). What is the return value to this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute path you can use terminal.

To open it press `Command` + `Space` → type "`terminal`" → press `Return`.

Make sure you are in home folder. It should look like this `YOUR_PC_NAME:~ USERNAME`. If no type `cd ~` → press `Return`.

Use `cd` - **c**hange **d**irectory and `ls` - **l**ist file**s** commands to locate your file.
When done, you will see that file listed with `ls` command. Just type `pwd` - **p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory than, to show absolute path to current folder.

Terminal commands and theirs usage [here](https://github.com/0nn0/terminal-mac-cheatsheet#core-commands).